# Why am I getting a CoreData error in my iOS or OSX app when I'm not using CoreData?

Tags: ios, core-data, git-lfs

I get the following error during a build.

"API Misuse: Attempt to serialize store access on non-owning coordinator (PSC = 0x7fb5ae208890, store PSC = 0x0) CoreData

Why am I getting a CoreData error in my app? I'm not using CoreData!

Answer (score 3):

This message is not referring to your use of CoreData, rather it is referring to Xcode's internal use in order to manage part of your project.

One possibility (it happened to me) is that there is corruption in one of the .xcassets files in your project.

In my case a problem with git-lfs meant that the .xcasset file did not have contents.  Correcting this (in my case with a git-lfs pull) meant that once the assets within the .xcassets file were available, the compilation error was fixed.

So in general check .xcassets files and any other Xcode managed project resources that might require use of CoreData internally to XCode

Answer (score 3):

I just wasted two days to this.

It seems to be triggered when using Xcode 14 1024 pt single size icon xcassets alongside certain other assets.

Workaround was to go back to the old multiple size icon assets.

The other weird thing is that it only gives the error when archiving.

Answer (score 2):

I found the same issue in Xcode 14 and noticed I added only one app icon image of 1024x1024.

Though it was an Xcode feature, still digging into the problem of why this failed.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error in XCode 12.5.1. It might occur in other situations also, but in my case, it turned out to be due to having two assets in the same asset library with the same name. The two assets had different file extensions, and the error occurred even when they were in different directories in the same asset library. I fixed it by giving all of the assets unique names.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem, but in my case it turned out to be 3 things:

1. Outdated pods, that were using Core Data (had to remove them);
2. Lottie added a file to the Assets folder, which triggered this error.
3. I had a couple of broken files in the Assets folder (no idea why). I needed to remove all assets, and manually readd all of them in order to localise the corrupted ones, and replace them with new instances.
   This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you code is not using CoreData API, this helped to fix the issue in Xcode 14.2

My app’s alternate icon were configured with a single size, and its primary icon (1024x1024 png) with individual sizes

This issue got resolved after I changed my primary app icon to single size which helped to archive the app successfully

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this issue on Xcode 14.2.  As I had always done, I set my images to be iPad 2x.  Once I changed them all to be Universal, the issue resolved.  I left the AppIcon set to single size.