# Unable to create a Build due to CoreData: API Misuse when there's no Core Data in the App, and the app builds for all Simulators

Tags: swift, build, compiler-errors, xcode12, xcode13

I am trying to create a build (Any iOS Device (arm64)), and I get an error:

> /.../CoreData:1:1:  API Misuse: Attempt to serialise store access on non-owning coordinator (PSC = 0x60000381b8e0, store PSC = 0x0)

The app compiles, and runs without any errors on all Simulators, and also on real devices (tested on 3 different iPhones). I have no logs in the console, only the error, not even a warning.

**My app is not using Core Data.**
I'm only saving a couple of user settings within UserDefaults.

The setup:
Xcode 13.1 (but the same thing happens on Xcode 12), Cocoapods, Swift 5, macOS Big Sur, SwiftUI 2.0 + Combine, I'm supporting targets from iOS 14+

What I've already tried:

- I have reviewed the assets folders - no duplicate names, it's not empty.
- I removed Lottie, and the file that it put within assets - didn't help.
- I have updated all my pods.
- I have tried cleaning Derived Data, clean builds, reinstalling pods, and restarting the Mac.
- There is no `Data(contentsOf:url)` in my code.

Any idea why this could be happening?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52126881/why-am-i-getting-a-coredata-error-in-my-ios-or-osx-app-when-im-not-using-coreda) doesn't help, I've tried all the suggested options. None of them apply here.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56559944/coredata-error-api-misuse-attempt-to-serialize-store-access-on-non-owning-coor) is actually using Core Data, so it doesn't apply, and neither do all the posts they mention, nor their suggestions in the comments.

Comment: Are any of the pods using CoreData?

Comment: not to my knowledge, no. I tried to search for CodeData within the whole project (including pods), nothing imports CoreData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue. What I did is:

- removed two outdated pods (that were using Core Data) - this moved things on, but I stil had the same error.
- Removed a file Lottie has added to Assets - this moved things forward, but didn't fix the situation.
- removing and readding all the Assets - one by one - manually - this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was suffering from this problem as well. When I saw Natalie's comment I immediately realised the problem.

I personally had "kra" files in my assets folder. Check the file types of your images.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33612768)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the Xcode 14 version, you may get this error of Assets AppIcon Issue Problem" on a single 1024 * 1024 px. You may change the icons to All Sizes. I have resolved this issue on my project. Try this one.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).